# PhpUnit bootstrap file not being found

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse Keplar and pdt is installed.

I want to set the path to the bootstrap file so I navigate to:

`Window -> Preferences -> PHP Tools -> PHPUnit`
There is the option to enter your Bootstrap file.

I put `\%p\tests\bootstrap.php` and run my tests and they fail saying could not find such and such a class.  This happens because the boostrap.php file is not being included.  If I set the bootstrap path to `\ProjectName\tests\bootstrap.php`, then it works.  Eclipse finds and includes the bootstrap file.

This isn't a good solution because I have several projects in my workspace and I would have to change this value each time I want to run another projects unit tests.

What am I doing wrong?  What am I missing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I think the best solution is to configure it on a per project basis.  You can right click on any project in the project explorer and select properties.

Then go to `PHP Tools` -> `PHPUnit` then check `Enable project specific settings`.

You can then set the `Bootstrap File` from there.  That value will only affect the current project.

Answer (score 3):

PTI PHPUnit plugin't haven't support for patch names with params.

I'm strongly recommend to switch into MakeGood plugin: https://github.com/piece/makegood  available on eclipse marketplace and pex repository (http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/). This plugin allows you to define project specific configuration.